# How to test Play/Pause button of video in Cypress?

Tags: button, get, css-selectors, cypress, click

I am working on automation testing of video play & pause button of website landing page using cypress. I have given location of play & pause button and performed click action but showing below error . Can someone please suggest a solution for automating both play/pause buttons?

Given below code of play/pause button:

**inspect html:** `<button class="vd-play-control vd-control vd-button vd-play" type="button" title="Play" aria-disabled="false"></button>                                                                                                                                  <button class="vd-play-control vd-control vd-button vd-pause" type="button" title="Pause" aria-disabled="false"></button>`

**code for play button:** `cy.get("button[class='vd-play-control vd-control vd-button vd-play']").click()`

**Error:** Timed out retrying after 8050ms:
cy.click() failed because this element:                                                                               has CSS pointer-events: none, inherited from this element: pointer-events: none prevents user mouse interaction.

Comment: Is your video player by any chance inside an `iframe` element?

Comment: No, Video player is not inside an iframe